# How to Enable IAP with GKE

Tags: express, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a basic react/express app with IAP authentication and deployed to google app engine and everything works as expected. Now i'm moving from app engine deployment to kubernetes, all things work except the user authentication with IAP on kubernetes. How do I enable IAP user authentication with kubernetes?

Do I have to create a kubernetes secret to get user authentication to work? https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto

Authentication code in my server.js https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users#cloud-identity-aware-proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Cloud IAP to be working with Kubernetes, you will need a group of one or more GKE instances, served by an HTTPS load balancer. The load balancer should be created automatically when you create an [Ingress object](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) in a GKE cluster.

Also required for enabling Cloud IAP in GKE: a domain name registered to the address of your load balancer and an App code to verify that all requests have an [identity](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto).

Once these requirements have been achieved, you can move forward with [enabling Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto#enabling_iap) on Kubernetes Engine. This includes the steps to set up Cloud IAP access and creating OAuth credentials.

You will need to create a Kubernetes Secret to [configure BackendConfig for Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto#kubernetes-configure). The BackendConfig uses a Kubernetes Secret to wrap the OAuth client that you create when enabling the Cloud IAP.

Comment: Is there documentation for registering a domain name to the load balancer?

Comment: You can register a domain name through [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/about/) or another domain registrar of your choice if you do not have one. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2b_using_an_ingress) will show you the step-by-step to configuring your domain name to the IP address of your HTTPS load balancer with Ingress.

Comment: Thanks! Another question, if I now want to deploy this application to AWS Kubernetes, will the IAP authentication work? Or do I need to rethink authentication when moving away from GKE?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an Ingress and enable IAP on the backend service

Create a BackendConfig object:

```yaml
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: app-bc
spec:
  iap:
    enabled: true
    oauthclientCredentials:
      secretName: oauth-client-secret
```

attached it to the service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "app-bc"}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

and then create the ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: ingress-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: ""
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: app-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

You can find the full tutorial here [hodo.dev/posts/post-26-gcp-iap/](https://hodo.dev/posts/post-26-gcp-iap/)

Comment: Ingress works well if the port I want to access is an HTTP port. How can i access/expose an arbitrary TCP port on a kubernetes svc to IAP?

Comment: IAP is an HTTP only service that uses http Authorization header to identify users. If you need to expose an arbitrary TCP port using IAP you can explore the `gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel` option to connect to one of the cluster nodes https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#console_3.